# System Tray Notifications when app in background or killed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am very new to Java and Android development and have a query about how Firebase Cloud Messaging is able to receive and display notifications in the system tray when the host app is in the background or dead.  I can understand how it might work when backgrounded - a Firebase service from the imported Firebase packages could still be running.  But when it is dead, surely any service component of the app is also terminated?

Is Firebase FCM using another running service/app (e.g. Google Play Services) to receive the notifications when it is backgrounded or not running?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: I would add Android and Java tags to your post to increase your audience.